# Is "strict limitation" a good collocation?

Tags: collocations

Is it correct to say "strict limitation"?

> Governments should levy **strict limitations** on the tools of trade to
> deter the dirty business of drugs.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it is. Why do you suspect that it isn't? You can search Google ngrams to see how often it appears in the Google Books corpus:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strict+limitation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Comment: Thanks. because I did not find it in collocation dictionary.

Comment: @a.toraby A word of advice: don't worry too much about "collocations".  They are something that ESL teachers seem to care a lot about and native speakers never think about, and it's impossible to find a list of all possible words that are used together.